# How to get Firebase App Distribution to work for different flavors with Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, firebase-app-distribution

I have an issue with Firebase Distribution configuration. Here's a part of my `build.gradle` in Kotlin DSL

```
flavorDimensions("dim")
productFlavors {
    
    create("fl1") {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".fl1"
        setDimension("dim")
        firebaseAppDistribution {
            releaseNotes = "$name"
            groups = "group-fl1"
        }
    }

    create("fl2") {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".fl2"
        setDimension("dim")
        firebaseAppDistribution {
            releaseNotes = "$name"
            groups = "group-fl2"
        }
    }

}
```

Flavor 1 and flavor 2 are uploaded to 2 different Firebase projects - therefore I have two `google-services.json` files in: `src/fl1` and `src/fl2`.

From observation Firebase App Distribution plugin uses always the config from second `firebaseDistribution` block. It looks like this is not set to flavor but globally.
When I invoke for example `assembleFl1Debug appDistributionUploadFl1Debug` the correct .apk lands in correct Firebase project, but both release notes and groups are not correct.
Anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reported this to Firebase support and just received a confirmation that it is bug, but no workaround or fix date is scheduled yet :(
This concerns only build.gradle files written in Kotlin DSL.

Comment: do you have a link to that bug report?

Comment: No, Firebase Support handled this by email. I can forward you their message. Right now we are forced to use the CLI to make this work with Kotlin DSL

Comment: Do you have a link to a support ticket they may have created? I'm running into a similar issue now: I want to change the artifactPath on per-variant basis, but the extension is registered per-Project instead of per-Task.

Comment: @user2290148 how do you fixed it via CLI?

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug, but until it's fixed, instead of `firebaseAppDistribution { ... }`, you may use:

```
configure<AppDistributionExtension> {
  ...
}
```

That way you can make a dynamic configuration that doesn't get overriden.

Comment: This has the very same result. Apparently, distribution configuration falls to the last configuration on Gradle KTS :|